# Displaying the output of an api response in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am able to post an api call and receive a '200' response, however I am unable to retrieve and display content in the printed output. The full code making the request is further below:

The results i'm getting from this block of code,

```
  SET @name = Trim(field(@rows, 1, 1))
    OUTPUTLINE(CONCAT(@name, " << <<<<<<<< RESULT >> ", @I ))
```

is...

```
Connection << <<<<<<<< RESULT >> 1 Vary 
<< <<<<<<<< RESULT >> 2 Access-Control-Allow-Origin 
<< <<<<<<<< RESULT >> 3 Access-Control-Allow-Headers 
<< <<<<<<<< RESULT >> 4 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 
<< <<<<<<<< RESULT >> 5 Access-Control-
.........
```

Error To AMP Script code is:

---

FULL CODE:

```
%%[
var @payload, @postRequest, @response, @responseRows, @countRows
  
set @payload = '{
  "phoenixEnabled": true,
  "strategies": ["visual-search"],
  "sessionId": "25380123960931531539370197404204",
  "customerId": "rad2021_660465629",
  "articleId": "60493879",
  "targetRecommendations": {}
}'

set @postrequest = HTTPPost2("https://api.geedo.com/recommendation/v1/resolver", 'application/json', @payload, true, @response, @responseRows)
IF @postrequest == 200 THEN
 OUTPUTLINE(CONCAT(@response))
ELSE
 OUTPUTLINE(CONCAT('HTTP request was unsuccessful'))
ENDIF

]%%

status code: %%=v(@postrequest)=%%
<br><hr>

%%[
var @countRows

set @countRows = RowCount(@responseRows)
IF @countRows > 0 THEN
 FOR @I = 1 TO @countRows DO
  SET @rows = row(@responseRows, @i)
]%%
<script runat = "server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
try {
</script>

%%[
SET @name = Trim(field(@rows, 1, 1))
OUTPUTLINE(CONCAT(@name, " << <<<<<<<< RESULT >> ", @I))
]%%
<script runat = "server" >
} catch (Errors_1) {
  Variable.SetValue("@errorMessage_2", Stringify(Errors_1.message) + Stringify(Errors_1.description));
} 
</script>  
%%[
 NEXT @I
ENDIF
]%%
```

Error To AMP Script code is : %%=v(@errorMessage_2)=%%

Comment: Have you tried just stringifying the whole response instead of Errors_1.message? Is it possible you aren't receiving an error thus the lack of print?

Comment: stringify was the solution in the end